# ImportError: No module named pyautogui after installing with anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror, pyautogui, conda-forge

Edit 2: Does it require admin permissions? 
After installing anaconda on Windows and trying these commands to install:

```
>>pip install pyautogui
>>conda install -c conda-forge pyautogui
>>conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pyautogui
>>conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pyautogui
```

I recieve an ImportError

```
>>> import pyautogui
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

The pyautogui commands also do not work. There were no errors during thale Anaconda installation for Windows 10 installed on Windows 10.

Comment: Hello sir, do you tried activated the environment and after that install pyautogui?

Comment: Yes I did activate it

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly using conda to manage your environments, I was having a similar error on Mac and the following worked for me.

1. conda update conda
2. conda config --add channels conda-forge
3. conda config --set channel_priority strict

And then, $ conda install -n envName pyautogui, didn't work. So instead I activated the environment I wanted it in and used pip, like so:

1. conda activate envName
2. pip install pyautogui

This worked and I now have pyautogui in the environment I need it in. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this on the anaconda console:

```
  pip install -U pyautogui
```

And make sure It has been installed.

Comment: Anaconda terminal shows it has been installed. It shows "Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade" on all requirements.